# Redis keys as a regex?

Tags: regex, redis

I have to create a redis database with keys as regex patterns(URL pattern: May be I should say just URL path). So when a URL comes in to my application I need to see which pattern it fits in and get the key. Does redis already provide any easier way to do the pattern matching?

```
  Any thoughts to improve the logic is appreciated.
```

Regards,
Lalith

Comment: have you tried the keys command? That command supports regex input.

Comment: Yes. But again I have to go through all the keys and find the matching key.. I was curious if redis has any commands to do that. It will be definitely faster if the computation runs in redis.

Answer (score 3):

```
redis-cli keys "user:*" | grep "user:[0-9]\+$" | xargs redis-cli DEL
```

This is taken from [Here](https://gist.github.com/mattweyant/2870203)

Comment: I don't think using keys is a good idea, keys is just for dev purposes, or in very rare situation.

From the doc:
Warning: consider KEYS as a command that should only be used in production environments with extreme care. It may ruin performance when it is executed against large databases. This command is intended for debugging and special operations, such as changing your keyspace layout. Don't use KEYS in your regular application code. If you're looking for a way to find keys in a subset of your keyspace, consider using SCAN or sets.

Answer (score 2):

[antirez has his lua-scripting branch](https://github.com/antirez/redis/tree/2.2-scripting) up.  Give it a try ;)

Comment: broken link fix would nice

Answer (score 1):

You could maintain two structures:

1 - First a [list](http://redis.io/commands#list) with all your keys. I mean, all your url-regex to match your urls. This should be updated every time you create another url-regex. Also you could have this in memory inside your application, so from time to time you read this list to update the items.

2 - Second the url-regex keys. This is the keys you where referring to, so here you put your values, whatever they are.

I don't think using `keys` is a good idea. It's not for production usage, at least not with business logic making use of it.

From the doc [keys](http://redis.io/commands/KEYS):

> Warning: consider KEYS as a command that should only be used in production environments with extreme care. It may ruin performance when it is executed against large databases. This command is intended for debugging and special operations, such as changing your keyspace layout. Don't use KEYS in your regular application code. If you're looking for a way to find keys in a subset of your keyspace, consider using SCAN or sets.

Comment: You are correct that `keys` should not be used in production environments, however it has nothing to do with "business logic" and everything to do with performance.

Comment: @Madbreaks yes, you are right, it's all about performance. What I meant was that you could use it in production but not for every request, or to do a massive use of it trying to query and filter your keys and then applying some logic on it, but you could use it as a helper to your environment. I used to have a large cluster with 32 Redis instances, so I built a tool to manage my production cluster and this tool did some use of `keys` and it was production, but it wasn't a massive use of it, it was managed, this way you can or you could, but it would be better to avoid it anyway...

Answer (score 1):

Quick and production ready examply with `redis-py` client:

```
r = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0, decode_responses=True)
keys: List[str] = [k for k in r.scan_iter(match="norgx:but:blob:*", count=1000)]
```

now you have a list of all keys of interest and perform the regex on them (which are not supported by the `SCAN` command. The `count` reduces ping/pong overhead on big databases and is the scanned batch size before matching.